# Branch is behind 'GitHub/master' by 1 commit

Tags: git, github

New to git and having an issue.

**Commit ab30d85: "Github/Master" - Test 


Commit d4f6492: "Master" - Fixed error**

I need to delete and remove the ab30d85 commit and make the d4f6492 the master for github. When I try to revert the test commit I get the error below. Please help.

On branch master
Your branch is behind 'GitHub/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've deleted the commit on your local, and force push to the master branch to update it as per your local branch using

`git checkout master; git push -f`

That being said, please know that the master branch on github will be force updated with your local branch. This is not a recommended practice.

Comment: Already on 'master'
Your branch is behind 'GitHub/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Comment: Since it's not a good practice to allow forced updates to master, maybe it's blocked for your repository, is it a personal repo? if not there are high chances for that.

Follow to unblock force pushes: https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/admin/developer-workflow/blocking-force-pushes-to-a-repository

Answer (score 1):

You have options:

`git rebase origin/master` will rework you local branch to include the ab30 commit and the apply you d4f commit. You will need to force push after fixing any merge conflicts to get this onto the remote branch.

`git push --force` will replace the remote branch with your local copy. Not good practice in general

Comment: Ok, after rebasing, you can do a ```git revert ab30d85```. Do the 2 commits have overlapping changes to the same source?

Comment: If you want to just delete the commit on origin/master without having a revert commit, then clone the repo somewhere else, do a ```git reset HEAD~1 --hard``` (this will hard reset one commit back, then force push. In future, I would suggest you create a new branch for the work you are doing off master to prevent this kind of confusion

Comment: All I really need to do is completely kill the ab30d85 commit. And make the d4f6492 commit the master for everything. Seems impossible

Comment: you can just run ``` git push --force``` and your local branch will overwrite the origin. But just be sure that the branch you have locally is what you want on origin master, as itll overwrite it in an unrecoverable way